# Mongodb- embedded vs Indexes

Tags: mongodb, indexing

My question is pretty simple.  I am building my first application with mongodb.  Up until now, i have always used sql.  I have read a lot of information about embedding documents versus linked documents.

My question to the mongodb veterans is: Is there a huge difference in speed/performance if I used indexed links/queries apposed to embedded docs?  If there is a huge difference can you please explain why?  Thank you.

Again, i am new to mongodb and just don't want to get off on the wrong foot.  thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is an enormous difference between references and embedded docs.

An embedded document is stored *in* the document in the same disk location as the rest of the doc's fields, so there's no additional network round-trips or disk seeks to retrieve the embedded document when you query the document as a whole.

DBRefs, on the other hand, are simply the _id of a document in another collection. It will take an additional roundtrip and additional disk seeks to get the "linked" document. See the spec for DBRefs here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References#DatabaseReferences-DBRef

You should try to optimize your most common query by including in a single document all the info needed to satisfy that query.

Comment: Follow up question to that is does the embedded doc have it's own size limit or does it add to the size of the parent doc?  I am worried that if all docs are embedded then the parent doc may reach the size limit?  Is this possible or is something i do not have to worry about?  Thanks.

Comment: For example, if i was building a contact list.  I had a parent document called users and that user document had embedded document called "contacts".  Is it a problem if the user had like 50,000 contacts?  Would this cause a size problem.  Or better yet lets say the user was keeping track of "contacts", "transactions", "date", etc., all embedded into the user document.  This could potentially make the parent/user document huge if they had like 50,000 contacts, 10,000 transactions, 30,000 dates/appointments, etc.  Please advise.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok another concern is if things are embedded then you cannot run reports across records.  For example lets say that each parent record had embedded records of transactions and you wanted to run a report for all transaction in the company (not user specific)  This could not be done easily if they were embedded.  Correct?

Comment: Yes, embedded docs are included in the size limit for the doc as a whole. Though, the 16MB document size is not something you are going to hit in most reasonable applications. The King James Bible is 4MB of plain text.

Comment: As for reports -- I advise you to structure your documents so the most common queries are fast. You can run reports on embedded documents, you just need to do some work in your application code. E.g., to count the number of contacts total, in Python:

`sum(len(user['contacts']) for user in db.users.find())`

Unlike SQL, MongoDB's query language isn't intended for doing *all* the work of aggregating your data, some of the logic for complex reports will be in your application code.

MongoDB 2.1's aggregation framework will make more complex reports possible in the database itself.

db.users